# How to interact with flask app while it is running?

Tags: python, flask

How to use `flask shell / cli` or any other option to interact with my running flask app in a non-interrupting way, so pdb is not good...

For example let's say I have the following app:

```
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)
received_data = []


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def slash():
    data = request.data
    if data not in received_data:
        received_data.append(data)
    return request.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I send a couple requests:

```
➤➤ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000 -d {'a':'1'}
> {a:1}

➤➤ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000 -d {'b':'2'}
> {b:2}

...
```

And now I want to fire up a console and check the value of the global variable `received_data` in a non-interrupting way while the app is still running. Also I would like to interact with the app in a similar manner to the rails console where you can do: app.get, app.post, ex: `app.post('/', {"this" => "that"})`

Comment: Why you need something like this?

Comment: @SebastianOpałczyński maybe this example is not very good. I want to use the console to interact with the app while it is running... like you can do with the rails console... for example I want to access my models instead of querying the db

Comment: Oh, get it - something like django shell :)

Comment: I've found some articles:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/23/
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/shell/

It looks that this require some effort to work - but it also looks that this is doable.

Comment: Not what you want but may help solve the problem. Try [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can send any kind of request and get the return value within their GUI.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is add a endpoint

```
@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def getData():
    print(received_data)
    return "OK", 200
```